# Need help understanding this block of code (java)

Tags: java

```
public class Bicycle {

private int cadence;
private int gear;
private int speed;

public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
    gear = startGear;
    cadence = startCadence;
    speed = startSpeed;
}
```

when you write gear = startGear; what does this actually do? does it temporary set the value of gear as whatever your input is for the time-being, then it resets back to zero? Is this called instance of a variable?

And can someone explain to me what exactly is an "instance of an object"? is there one in here? 
I thought an instance of an object is when someone writes Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle(); and bike1 is an instance of an object.  Sorry I am a total noob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) ;
```

This is constructor for class `Bicycle` that takes three arguments which are all of type `int`. Constructor should bear the same name that of the class.

**when you write gear = startGear; what does this actually do?**

To such copy of variables, you are actually assigning the value of passed argument to it.

---

**What exactly is an "instance of an object"?**

There is nothing called instance of an object. You have *instance for a class*. And each instance has it's own class member variables. Infact, instance and object are synonyms and are often interchangeably used.

---

Keep the descriptive part apart and understand this diagram -

1. This is the basic structure of class `Bicycle` -
   [image: Bicycle structure]
2. Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle(10, 4, 75) ;

When said `new Bicycle(10, 4 75);`, `Bicycle` class is instantiated. By instantiation means -

- Allocating memory for class members;
- Calling the class constructor, by default.

The operator `new` returns the address of where the object residing on heap. So, in our case `bike1` is pointing to such memory location.
[image: bike1]
`(10,4,75)` are passed as parameters to the constructor and since you are doing the necessary assignment operations in the constructor, 10, 4, 75 are assigned to `cadence, gear, speed` respectively.

To keep short, a copy of class variables is obtained when a class is instantiated.

Comment: How come I don't just do public Bicycle(int Cadence, int Speed, int Gear) ;
this way the values will be passed into it directly?

Comment: @CuriousStudent - I am just mentioning the prototype of class construtor, as an example. What you are doing is you are placing the constructor's definition as a part of class definition itself.

Comment: what if I do something like this public Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
?

Comment: @CuriousStudent- Diagrams are added for better understanding. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

So a Bicycle is an object. As such it is responsible for everything there is to know about a bicycle. So it must remember information about itself, so that at a later point in time if you ask the bicycle about itself, it can tell you info.

This code is a constructor, it initializes the Bicycle object.

So what we are doing is telling this bicycle your gear is 'startGear' some value passed into the constructor. The Bicycle saves that value in a field, so that it can reference it later.